# Where can I find how much it costs to play Ultima Online?

Tags: ultima-online

From what the Wikipedia article states, Ultima Online is still running? Their news feed on [their website](http://uo.com), also has updates so it looks like it's still running.

I don't think it's free to play, but I can't figure out specifically how much it would cost to start playing, nor how much the monthly fees are.  Their website is hard to navigate; where can I find how much the initial fee is and the monthly cost thereafter?

Comment: Asking a games monthly fee seems too localized for the same reason asking the cost of a game is too localized.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Purchasing a version of [Ultima Online: Stygian Abyss](http://store.origin.com/store/ea/en_US/pd/productID.156849100/sac.true) for $29.99 covers new account creation and 30 days of game time.

The current monthly fee is $12.99

source: http://www.uo.com/costs.html

Answer (score 0):

You can play Ultima Online for free on several free shards. Simply google "utlima online free shard".

Euro prices on the official servers are:

- 13,99 € : 1 month
- 39,99 € : 3 months
- 67,99 € : 6 months

Most likely the same amount in USD.

You can buy several addons and gametime cards in the Origin Store (Actually cheaper than via the Account Management).

The best option would be to you try the 14-Day Trial over on the official Ultima Online Hompage.

Comment: wouldn't free shards be against the TOS?

Comment: Wikipedia offers some information: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultima_Online_shard_emulation